# Why is GPG file encryption so much slower than other AES implementations?

Tags: encryption, aes, pgp, file-encryption, gnupg

Correct me if I'm wrong: When encrypting a file, GPG creates a one-off AES encryption key and encrypts *that* key using RSA. This is supposedly to take advantage of AES's superior performance when handling larger amounts of data.

If that's true, then why is `gpg --encrypt` so much slower than, for example, `p7zip`'s AES-256 encryption?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let's try...

First, I create a 500 MBytes file full of random bytes:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/foo bs=1000000 count=500
```

then I encrypt it using GnuPG, measuring the time taken by that process ("`keyID`" is the UID of the public key I am using):

```
time gpg -r "keyID" --cipher-algo AES256 --compress-algo none -o /tmp/bar --encrypt /tmp/foo
```

Total time on my machine (Intel i7 at 2.7 GHz, 64-bit mode, GnuPG 2.0.22):

```
3.77s user 0.55s system 99% cpu 4.328 total
```

so an encryption bandwidth of 115 MBytes per second: that's not so bad ! Now let's try again, but this time without deactivating the compression (i.e. let's remove the "`--compress-algo none`" options):

```
20.99s user 0.79s system 98% cpu 22.038 total
```

which is 5 times slower. So there you have it: it is not the encryption which is "slow", it is the compression (although more than 20 MB/s can still be decently fast for many usages).

---

115 MB/s is consistent with a "portable" implementation of AES. Code which uses the [specialized AES opcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) (which are available on my i7) would be faster, up to, say, 300 to 400 MB/s (though AES-NI opcodes have a very high throughput, they also have a non-negligible latency, which means that the best performance requires parallel processing, i.e. [CTR mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29); but the [OpenPGP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) mandates [CFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29), which is sequential).

Anyway, since a good mechanical hard disk tops at about 120 MB/s, while a very good Internet access (optic fiber) will be below 10 MB/s, one can say that 115 MB/s of raw encryption speed is sufficient.

Comment: Note that you need GnuPG 2.x to take advantage of these AES opcodes. GnuPG 1.4 (or rather the underlying libgcrypt) does not support this.

Comment: Retrospectively, my assumption on Internet access speed is a bit outdated. A number of end users have gigabit now, i.e. about 110 MB/s. Still not enough to make encryption the bottleneck.

Comment: What's the rationale in having `--compress-algo` enabled by default? The plaintext/cyphertext will be the same size, won't they? So why compress it, rather than leaving it up to the user? (for instance I'm using `xz` first, and was wondering why my process was slow) Does this vary with `--symmetric`?